how to populate a collection field with data from json file using spring @Value annotation?
I have a field in my service that I want to populate with data from the json file:
@Value("classpath:mockedData.json")
private List<BigDecimal> someData;

My json file looks like that:
[23, 45, 155, 374, 22, 99.99, 100, 101, 115, 209]

What is the correct, cleanest possible way to make this work in SpringBoot application?
This is the error I'm currently getting:
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List'; Character array is missing "e" notation exponential mark.

Is there some magical annotation that I could use, which would take care of this? Seems like something that could be available "from the box" but I'm having a hard time finding a way to make it work..
Thanks!
I've tried googling around to find the answer. Tried using @JsonFormat and @JsonSerialize annotations with different arguments. Tried searching Spring docs also, couldn't find anything that would work

The Value annotation doesn't work this way.  If you change that property  to be type String, you'll see that what's being injected is just the text, classpath:mockedData.json
There are a couple of ways to load this, since this is presumably a Component, or one of the other stereotypes that enables autowiring, you can add a PostConstruct method to read the file with a pure ObjectMapper into your array.
@PostConstruct
public void loadData() throws IOException {
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:mockedData.json");
    TypeReference<List<BigDecimal>> typeReference = new TypeReference<>() {};

    this.someData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(file, typeReference);
}

Your other option is to place your list directly into your properties file (or any properties file you want to activate); then, you can use @Value to load them.
Simply add a property to your application.[properties][yaml] that is a list of numbers.
someData: 1,2,3

Then you can inject them with @Value
@Value("${someData}")
private List<BigDecimal> someData;

